# PHP Curl Json: multiple outputs

Tags: php, curl

I'm currently trying to get every title of my JSON decoded output in a variable

This is what works for me as curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.irail.be/disturbances/?format=json&lang=nl',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'cache-control: no-cache',
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Decode JSON response and get only the data needed:
$response = json_decode($response);
$response = $response->disturbance[0];
var_dump($response);

$name = $response->title;
echo $name;
```

When I remove the [0] behind disturbance I am getting a blank $name. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Post the output of `print_r($response);` so we can see what's in the JSON.

Comment: @AlexHowansky https://imgur.com/a/VMxZNYw

Comment: Please post the code, not pictures of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your objects via the **keys**, but "disturbance" is not a key, it is a **value** that the key `type` can take.

You need first to filter your data to get only the items with `type = 'disturbance'`, and then you can get the titles.

Here is an example :

```
$response = json_decode($response); 
$disturbanceItems = array_filter($response, function ($item){return $item->type == 'disturbance';}); 

echo $disturbanceItems[0]->title ;
```